# AndEngine drawing 2D tiled game field

Tags: android, andengine

I'm in process of developing simple android puzzle game. I decided to choose `andEngine` as an engine for my game.

In my game I have a `gameField [][]` array, which represents a game field, where each element is a cell of game level and consists of a type of the cell (for ex. `FLOOR` of `WALL`). During the game, state of cell can be changed (for ex. `DOOR_CLOSED` changed to `DOOR_OPENED`), but it happens rarely, almost all the elements of gameField don't change.

I tried to implement that by adding `repaint` method to `updateHandler`, which would paint sprites for each cell every tick. But I wonder wouldn't be that approach a wasting of memory and processor time? What is the best practise for doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about having that multidimensional array of yours filled with, say, an extension of TiledSprites.  Something like the following:

```
public class Door extends TiledSprite {

    private boolean isOpen = false;
    private static final int DOOR_CLOSED = 0;
    private static final int DOOR_OPEN = 1;

    public Door() {
        this(0, 0, doorTextureRegion, vertexBufferObjectManager);
        this.setCurrentTileIndex(DOOR_CLOSED);
    }

    public open() {
        this.isOpen = true;
        this.setCurrentTileIndex(DOOR_OPEN);
    }

    public close() {
        this.isOpen = false;
        this.setCurrentTileIndex(DOOR_CLOSE);
    }

}
```

In your scene, you attach all the TiledSprites as children of the scene.  Iterate over the array in an initialization method, say.  You shouldn't have to constantly poll and redraw--AndEngine takes care of that for you.

Comment: I just saw your answer :) Thanks for reply, I've already implement similar approach in my game :)